# How to classify data into N classes + one "garbage" class (or leave some data out)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, noise

I am trying to classify images of cells into N classes ("cell 1", "cell 2" ...) but some of the images are just noise and I would like to either **not** classify them or put them into a "garbage" class.
I have tried the latter, but it is not very successful and I suspect it is because my "garbage" class is very heterogenous.

Any suggestions on how to allow excluding some data from classification, or classify it as noise?

I am using python and sklearn, but I would welcome either specific python/sklearn tips or generic machine learning algorithms.

Comment: your "garbage class" approach is a popular one, So perhaps investigate further about why the model isn't performing too well without any pre-assumptions. See if your model just isn't performing well, garbage class or not.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh do you mean that models are never put off by one class being very heterogenous?

Comment: well, it does impact the model, but if there's separability between the non garbage classes, then the model picks up on those features and gives good performance. I suppose it depends on whether you're asking from a theoretical perspective or a practical one, practically, the "O" class approach has been utilized before.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to

1. make a binary classifier that classifies into
   "garbage"/"non-garbage" classes
2. make a regular N-classes classifier that classifies "non-garbage"
   inputs